# Align buttons side by side - bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Take a look at the below example.

[Link to Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/U0L2BCDGUt)

I want the `<a>` tag to be besides `Button 2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap uses 12 column grid. Right now two buttons take the whole available space (both 6-column width) leaving no space for the third. You can layout your buttons as 5+5+2 columns. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md col-md-5">Button 1</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-md col-md-5">Button 2</button>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-md col-md-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://www.bootply.com/RAqyEiTp1i

You want to place the third button outside the row container, you can position it absolutely relatively to the col group:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-beside"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-beside {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

#### Demo: http://www.bootply.com/5n3y1uZDng

Comment: that could have worked had i wanted all the 3 buttons to be within the size of the above textbox. I want the `<a>` tag to be besides the current button 2.

Comment: one of the issues is tht, in mobile mode the button 3 appears displaced.